# How to fetch a set of grouped data through postgres query

Tags: postgresql

My db table data is,

```
id,name,start_time,expire_time,status
1,Jim,2021-08-12 22:00:00,2021-08-15 22:00:00,completed
2,Joe,2021-08-12 22:00:00,2021-08-15 23:00:00,completed
3,Tom,2021-08-12 22:00:00,2021-08-15 24:00:00,completed
4,brad,2021-08-13 17:00:00,2021-08-15 22:00:00,completed
5,Jim,2021-08-14 22:00:00,2021-08-15 13:00:00,completed
6,Tom,2021-08-14 22:00:00,2021-08-15 14:00:00,completed
7,Joe,2021-08-14 22:00:00,2021-08-15 215:00:00,completed
```

i need to group this table by start_time and fetch only the group distinct by the name. For example in above table, row 1,2 and 3 are having same start value and 5,6 and 7 are having another same value. Since those 2 set of records are having same name i need to render only 1 which is ordered by the start time. Then row 4 will be there as a single record. So the final output should be

```
1,Jim,2021-08-12 22:00:00,2021-08-15 22:00:00,completed
2,Joe,2021-08-12 22:00:00,2021-08-15 23:00:00,completed
3,Tom,2021-08-12 22:00:00,2021-08-15 24:00:00,completed
4,brad,2021-08-13 17:00:00,2021-08-15 22:00:00,completed
```

So i tried below query. but i could get a correct result

```
Select distinct on (name) * 
from table
where status='completed'
group by start_time
```

Suggest a correct query for my case

Comment: You shouldn't need the `group by` if you're using `distinct`.  The only issue is that SQL doesn't guarantee WHICH of the duplicate records it will return.  Does that matter to you?

Comment: yes i need to get the oldest start_time set

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the earliest start time is associated with the earliest expire time, this should will work:

```
SELECT id, name, min(start_time) AS start_time,
       min(expire_time) AS expire_time, status
FROM table
WHERE status='completed'
GROUP BY name,status;
```

Comment: when u include id in the group by clause, it will list down all the records

Comment: Yes, I should have known better.